# Facebook API: Post on Facebook wall is not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm a Facebook app developer. I have developed some apps. Everything was working good.
I have not developed any apps for the past 6 months. Now I started to develop an app with existing code. It is not working like what I expected. I don't know why. I have checked the coding with old apps. Everything is fine.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {

    } else {
        loginUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=" + appId + "&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/appname/&scope=email,user_activities,user_likes,publish_actions,read_stream,publish_stream";
        top.location.href   = loginUrl;
    }
}, true);
```

I couldn't post on my facebook wall. Error ((#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action) is coming.
Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authorization did not work. Use FB.login for authorization: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.1

Important note: Call it on user interaction, and NOT in the (asynchronous) callback function of FB.getLoginStatus. You should not directly present the authorization screen/popup to the user right when he opens your App/Website anyway.

Also, publish_stream is deprecated, publish_actions is the only permission you need for posting.